# Can I sync a SQLite.swift database to WatchOS?

Tags: swift3, ios10, watchos-3, sqlite.swift

I have an application that uses [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) to save a list of shopping items. It works quite well, and is deeply rooted in the app. But I've been getting asked to make a WatchOS app that has the same items on your wrist.

My issue with this, is that all the ways of syncing the data between two devices is through `NSUserDefaults`. But doing that would mean uprooting my entire way of saving data, so is there a way to sync my SQL database onto WatchOS by using [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course: sync the database (or the shared part of it) yourself.

Read the "Communicating with the Counterpart App" chapter of https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession and choose the best way to transfer your information.

Comment: Thank you so much! Probably should have done a little more research on the subject before asking.